# Are Dementors able to kill souls in the afterlife?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In the movie *The Deathly Hallows* Part 2, when Harry was speaking with his parents' souls and other wizards' souls in the woods, if a Dementor had suddenly shown up there, could it have consumed one of the souls speaking to Harry?

Moreover, if it is able to consume a soul in the afterlife, would the Dementors likely be trying to chase down all the souls in the afterlife to consume them all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would seem that the dementors would not be able to have any effect on the people that Harry "recalled" from the dead. In fact, on the contrary, the "recalled" people acted as patronuses and actually protected Harry from the effects of the dementors. From Chapter Thirty-Four:

> And he set off. The dementors’ chill did not overcome him; he passed through it with his companions, and they acted like Patronuses to him, and together they marched through the old trees that grew closely together, their branches tangled, their roots gnarled and twisted underfoot.

Comment: Plus the Ministry would probably have used a dementor to get rid of moaning myrtle - they use dementors for everything it seems.